# "Within a short time" vs "within a short period of time"

Tags: vocabulary

I am referring to sense 5 (time means period) of https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/time_1?q=time.

Is "Within a short time" equivalent to "within a short period of time" and are both equally idiomatic and have the same meaning? Given that time can be used in the sense of period, aren't phrase like 'time window/time frame/time period/period of time' a bit redundant?

Example sentences: "I do this within a short time" vs "I do this within a short period of time"

Comment: They’re equivalent. You can also say you do it *quickly*. There are often many ways to express a thought.

Comment: Redundancy is a difficult area. Sometimes, redundant phrases are more idiomatic than non-redundant ones, sometimes they're just needless clutter. Each needs to be looked at individually. Here, 'time slot' say can be more precise than the highly polysemous 'time', while 'I do this within a short period of time' does sound inflated. 'I can get this done quickly' is idiomatic in the UK.

Comment: Neither example sentences are idiomatic native English. What are you trying to say? "I will do this in a short while (because I do not have time now)" or "I can do this quickly"

Answer (score -1):

Both sentence fragments:

> within a short time ...

and

> within a short period of time ...

are sensewise, equivalent and idiomatic. However, if time is short, one would expect sentences to be short, hence the first - being shorter - sounds more natural whereas the latter sounds a little pedantic and ponderous. One might expect the latter sentence to appear in a computer manual or instruction booklet which do tend to pedantry.